# Why laravel 8 form validation request doesn't work as shown in documentation

Tags: laravel

I make custom request by

```
php artisan make:request UserUpdate
```

and then fill UserUpdate

```
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'=>'required|string',
        'email'=>'required|email',
    ];
}
```

after that call from controller

```
public function profilepost(UserUpdate $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->name = $request['name'];
    $user->email = $request['email'];
    $user->save();
    return back();
}
```

when submit form show error

> Target class [app\Http\Requests\UserUpdate] does not exist.

Why that happen? Laravel documentation are not correct? Can someone explain me?

Comment: try adding : use app\Http\Requests\UserUpdate; to your controller

Comment: yes added,but not work ```use app\Http\Requests\UserUpdate;```

Comment: Please share full code of your request

Comment: hello bro,solved not ```use app\Http\Requests\UserUpdate;``` ,answer is ```use App\Http\Requests\UserUpdate;``` . app to App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **I Know it's solved, but this could be useful!**

It's **good practice** to name the file/class like: `UpdateUserRequest` or `UserUpdateRequest`.

**Why?** It's more readable, other programmers understand what it does faster and
because of the specific name, class name collitions are avoided.

Remember if you have **multiple requests** on you project it's allways better to **organize them in folders**, example:

```
php artisan make:request User/UserUpdateRequest
```

This should create a request in User folder, and also with: `namespace App\Http\Requests\User`

**Last but not least** a better way to define the rules is:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
     'name' => ['required', 'string'],
     'email' => ['required', 'email'],
  ];
}
```

**Why?** This gives you the ability to add **custom rules** to the validations if needed!